# Creating dynamic children of a JSON object from data source

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, hierarchical-data, orgchart

I'm creating a plugin using [this library](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart) to create an organizational chart for my application (built on bubble.io) that gets the data from the application and wants that data to get inside the structure i.e parent children dynamically. The number of children of any node can be dynamic and needs to be entered through a loop and recursive function.

I have tried to create a JSON object dynamically but could not succeed in creating a recursive function inside a loop that will keep making children programmatically.
I have got the first node from data_source (ibrar) but after that, I have a record of thousand, and a 'children_text' field( can be more than 1 entry) stores a unique ID of the parent. I can also add a parent field if the solution asks for that.

[image]

```js
var len = properties.data_source.length();
var i;
var j;
let objj = {};
let hello = [];

let user = properties.data_source.get(0, len);

//extracting string properties from data_source
var name = user[0].get("name_text");
var title = user[0].get("designation_text");
  var image = user[0].get("picture_image");




$(function() {


  var styleTag = $(' <style> .orgchart { background: #fff; }.orgchart td.left, .orgchart td.right, .orgchart td.top { border-color: #aaa; } .orgchart td>.down { background-color: #aaa; } .orgchart .middle-level .title { -color: 699; }.orgchart .middle-level .content { border-color: #006699; }.orgchart .product-dept .title { background-color: #009933; } .orgchart .product-dept .content { border-color: #009933; } .orgchart .rd-dept .title { background-color: #993366; } .orgchart .rd-dept .content { border-color: #993366; } .orgchart .pipeline1 .title { background-color: #996633; } .orgchart .pipeline1 .content { border-color: #996633; } .orgchart .frontend1 .title { background-color: #cc0066; }.orgchart .frontend1 .content { border-color: #cc0066; } .orgchart .second-menu-icon {      transition: opacity .5s;      opacity: 0;      right: -20px;      top: 80px;  transform: rotate(270deg);    z-index: 2;      position: relative;    }    .orgchart .second-menu-icon::before { background-color: rgba(68, 157, 68, 0.5); }    .orgchart .second-menu-icon:hover::before { background-color: #449d44; }    .orgchart .node:hover .second-menu-icon { opacity: 1; }    .orgchart .node .second-menu {      display: none;      position: absolute;      top: 110px;  transform: scaleX(-1)rotate(90deg);    right: -70px;      border-radius: 35px;      box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #999;      background-color: #fff;      z-index: 1;    }    .orgchart .node .second-menu .avatar {      width: 60px;      height: 60px;      border-radius: 30px;      float: left;      margin: 5px;   } </style>');
  $('html > head').append(styleTag);

  var datascource = {
    'name': name,
    'title': title,
    'children': [{
        'name': 'Bo Miao',
        'title': 'department manager',
        'className': 'middle-level',
        'children': [{
            'name': 'Li Jing',
            'title': 'senior engineer',
            'className': 'product-dept'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Li Xin',
            'title': 'senior engineer',
            'className': 'product-dept',
            'children': [{
                'name': 'To To',
                'title': 'engineer',
                'className': 'pipeline1'
              },
              {
                'name': 'Fei Fei',
                'title': 'engineer',
                'className': 'pipeline1'
              },
              {
                'name': 'Xuan Xuan',
                'title': 'engineer',
                'className': 'pipeline1'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'name': 'Su Miao',
        'title': 'department manager',
        'className': 'middle-level',
        'children': [{
            'name': 'Pang Pang',
            'title': 'senior engineer',
            'className': 'rd-dept'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Hei Hei',
            'title': 'senior engineer',
            'className': 'rd-dept',
            'children': [{
                'name': 'Xiang Xiang',
                'title': 'UE engineer',
                'className': 'frontend1'
              },
              {
                'name': 'Dan Dan',
                'title': 'engineer',
                'className': 'frontend1'
              },
              {
                'name': 'Zai Zai',
                'title': 'engineer',
                'className': 'frontend1'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };



  $('#chart-container').orgchart({
    'data': datascource,
    'visibleLevel': 2,
    'nodeContent': 'title',
    'direction': 'l2r',
    'nodeID': 'id',
    'createNode': function($node, data) {
      var secondMenuIcon = $('<i>', {
        'class': 'oci oci-info-circle second-menu-icon',
        click: function() {
          $(this).siblings('.second-menu').toggle();
        }
      });
      var secondMenu = '<div class="second-menu"><img class="avatar" src=' + image + '></div>';
      $node.append(secondMenuIcon).append(secondMenu);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please fix your snippet to be a [mcve]. For now "properties" are missing

Comment: @mplungjan This example is working in the plugin environment of bubble.io as a script.

Comment: ". . . a recursive function inside a loop that will keep making children programmatically . . . " sounds like a description of the code that creates  child nodes inside an org chart  when it traverses the datasource object. That code would be in the `.orgchart` method, not in the posted code where the only "JSON" object (whatever that might be) would appear to be  `datasource`.  Could you explain the design of the task a little more in the post please?

Comment: properties is a predefined function that gets data from application's database

Comment: @traktor The link to the library has 20+ working examples. I have added a screenshot of the plugin I have created till now and added more description to it.